# django python - what language is this?

Tags: python, django

i am reading [django tutorial part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/) ... and i came across strange syntax 
what kind of language is it? python?
i tried to find but i couldn't.

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
<ul>
{% for question in latest_question_list %}
    <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

i have tried to look for a similiar syntax in google, but with no help.

Comment: that's django template language

Comment: [Django Template Tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/)

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the [Django Templating engine](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/#templates).